# react-leaflet with require js is displaying broken map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

The map is appearing out of the parent div and is displaying in a broken manner. I tried adding height for the map component and linking leaflet CSS in `index.html` as suggested on StackOverflow for similar issue. But nothing seems to fix my issue. Can anyone help me out here?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Map } from "react-leaflet";
import { TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import { Marker } from "react-leaflet";

class GeoData extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    render () {
        var center=[15.29, 74.124];
        return (
            <div style={{width:'1200px',height:'600px'}}>
                <p className="sub-head1">GEOGRAPHICAL DATA</p>
                <Map center={center} zoom={13} style={{ height: '80px'}}>
                <TileLayer
            attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
                    <Marker position={center} />
                </Map>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default GeoData;
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You have to import `leaflet.css`

Comment: I had tried importing it , require js throws script error